# Cannot make rules permanent in firewalld

Tags: firewalld

I am using [firewalld](https://firewalld.org/). I want to add a range of source IPs in the trusted zone. I can in fact do this:

```
❯ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.0.0/16
success
```

And I can confirm that the rules are working. But I don't want to do this ever time I start my computer. So I want to makes the rules permanent but that does not happen:

```
❯ sudo firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
Warning: NOT_ENABLED: ens32
success

❯ sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: ens32
```

When I restart, the rules are no more and I have to add them again.

Is there a way to make the rules permanent in `firewalld`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your rule as permanent when you define it:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.0.0/16 --permanent
```

and then verify that it is indeed permanent:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --list-sources --permanent
```

Comment: This worked but I wonder what the reason is. 
Also changing the zone to "trusted" before adding rules and making permanent also works, as in:

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --change-interface=ens32`, then, `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.0.0/16`, then `sudo firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`.